# How to show number in sequence in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 4 column in my database table with the name of id,number,city,country when i search country i show all capital city of that country but problem is it show the in non order sequence like

```
1   lahore    pakistan
10  karachi   pakistan
2   peshawar  pakistan
```

i try to write in order y number but failed here is mu query

```
$mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE country ='$name' ORDER BY number ASC ");
```

so i don't understand where i am wrong ..

Comment: you're ordering by number. assuming that's an numeric field, you'll get `1,2,10`. why aren't you doing `order by city`?

Comment: just change your `number` column type to `INT` or any other number type.

Comment: i am not order by city i am order by number which is integer

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your number is not really a number.  It's a string.  So in "order" 10 comes right after 1.

You need to have the field set up as a number OR you need to convert the value when you pull it.

Syntax for CONVERT:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

You should be able to just add the conversion at the point of the ORDER statement, like this:

```
$mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE country ='$name' ORDER BY CONVERT ( numeric(10) , number) ASC ");
```

Whereas this will work, and all...  A better and more correct solution to your problem is to use the correct data type.  That is, convert your field to a numeric type in the table.  Then you won't have to write stuff like this later.

Comment: durbnpoisn bro u understand my problem exactly i face same when to reaches above to 9 i dis order its sequence .can u please write full query how to convert in query

Comment: Added in request, with some other stuff.

Comment: try using UNSIGNED INTEGER in place of numeric.  You could also try doing the conversion at the SELECT level and the ORDER level.  Couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Your number field seems like string type (varchar). Alter your table's number field with data typs as integer. And try same query.
In string 10 comes before 2 thus you are getting result as 1 10 2.

Alter table will solve your issue. :)

Comment: i chnage number data type as int by it show in sequence in database not in php

Comment: It would be better and easy to debug  if you can share your php code.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $code = $_POST["text"];
        $session = $_POST["term"];
        
        $mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE subject ='$code' and session='$session' ORDER BY q_number ASC ");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){
        $questionnum = $row['q_number'];
        $question = $row['question'];
        $marks = $row['marks'];
        $answer = $row['answer'];
        ?>

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$code = $_POST["text"];
$session = $_POST["term"];

$mysql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `subject` WHERE subject ='$code' and session='$session' ORDER BY q_number ASC ");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($mysql)){
$questionnum = $row['q_number'];
$question = $row['question'];
$marks = $row['marks'];
$answer = $row['answer'];
?>